# managing visibility of relativelayout children

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I had to implement the expand/collapse(show/hide) a particular view on click of a some other view..Finally got it working but with a small problem.
I have a relative layout with two children: first is the textview and second is a linear layout.
On the click event of the textview i set the visibility(VISIBLE or GONE) of the following linear layout.
Now the problem is that after the linear layout is visible it somehow manages to hide the textview..
I tried `textview.bringToFront()` but it just makes the textview overlap the first row of the linearlayout ie the textview comes on top of the linear layout content.
I tried putting the textview in a linearlayout, but it makes no difference.
I tried setting the linear layout as BELOW. All in vain..
I know the textview exists because when i click the first row(which is overlapping the textview) the click event gets fired..
All i want is that no matter what my textview should be visible and the linear layout must take its position below the textview if it is visible..
**EDIT**

```
RelativeLayout wrapperlayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
//wrapperlayout.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//-------------HANDLE---------------------------
TextView txtHeader = new TextView(getActivity());
txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        RelativeLayout rParent =  (RelativeLayout) tv.getParent();
        LinearLayout lInner = (LinearLayout) rParent.getChildAt(1);

        if(lInner.isShown())
        {
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.expand, 0, 0, 0);
            //tv.bringToFront();
            lInner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //lInner.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up));
        }
        else{
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.collapse, 0, 0, 0);
            //tv.bringToFront();
            lInner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lInner.setTop(tv.getBottom());
            //lInner.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_down));
        }


    }
});
txtHeader.setText("Header");
txtHeader.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.expand, 0, 0, 0);
txtHeader.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


//--------------CONTENT-------------------------
LinearLayout lContent = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
lContent.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
lContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

HashMap<String, String> MySet = new HashMap<String, String>();
MySet = getData();
Iterator<String>RowItr = MySet.keySet().iterator();
int rowcnt = 0;
while (RowItr.hasNext()) {
    LinearLayout lRow = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lRow.setLayoutParams(lparams1);
    lRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView txtLbl = new TextView(getActivity());
    txtLbl.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    TextView txtVal = new TextView(getActivity());
    txtVal.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

    String Lbl = RowItr.next();
    txtLbl.setText(Lbl);
    if(rowcnt % 2 != 0)
        lRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dbe4f0"));
    else
        lRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    txtVal.setText(MySet.get(Lbl));
    lRow.addView(txtLbl);
    lRow.addView(txtVal);
    lRow.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

    lContent.addView(lRow);
    rowcnt++;
}                       
lContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

wrapperlayout.addView(txtHeader);
wrapperlayout.addView(lContent);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rPARAMS = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//rPARAMS.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, txtHeader.getId());
//rPARAMS.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lContent.getId());
wrapperlayout.setLayoutParams(rPARAMS);
```

Comment: Can you please upload some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution.. i tried setting margins..and it all worked out well.. te handle and content both are visible without hiding any other views..

Answer (score 0):

well you can store your LinearLayout as an instance variable, and simply call layout.setvisibility(View.GONE); in your onClick method. Doubt theres any other solution unless you want to save the parent(the layout that both of your views are attached to) and perform findViewById inside onClick or call getChildAt(1)  orso

Comment: just invoke this on lContent instead of lInner thhough make sure its instantiated. I also dont get your point here, why dont you use xml for this?

Comment: I cant use xml cause the data is database driven.. anyway, thanks.. I'll try that and get back..

Comment: why would it matter its database driven? You can still build your major layout elements, and add stuffs in your LinearLayout dynamicaly only. Try rewriting it properly and this should work.